# Wrong Anticipated Result

Tags: average

I tried to calculate the average time taken to encrypt text messages of various sizes in kilobytes, but I couldn't get the results I am anticipating. I don't know where the problem is.

[image]
[image]

The number of messages is 10.

Comment: It is obvious the Blowfish should have less average time.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).
Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are not view-able to some.